# Use a linux c++ library with PROC PROTO in SAS

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, sas

I would like to use my own library with the SAS PROC PROTO. I am using the university edition which appears to run on Linux.

I tried to do the following:
Compile my source file into a static library (because I am not sure which libc or other standard library are available or in which version thy could be available so I would like to include them all). I used the following: `g++ -static -std=c++11 -c foo.cpp -o libfoo.o` and then `ar rcs libfoo.a libfoo.o`

then I upload the libfoo.a on the SAS platform, and made a SAS program like the following:

```
%let root = /folders/foobar/; 

libname lib "&root";

proc proto package=lib.Foobar 
    Label="Foobar" ;

link "&root/libfoo.a" ;
```

However then I get the following error:

```
64         link "&root/libfoo.a" ;
 65         
 66         OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 ERROR: Unable to load 'libfoo.a'.
 ERROR: Extension Load Failure: OS Error: -1 (/folders/foobar/libfoo.a: invalid ELF header)
 ERROR: Unable to load extension: (/folders/foobar/libtrie.a)
 ERROR: Could not find extension: (libtrie.a)
 ERROR: Could not find extension: (libtrie.a)
```

From there I suppose SAS is expecting a dynamic library. so I suppose I should first link statically to include all the dependent libraries, and then link dynamically so that SAS could load it..

Is it the right approach and how is best to do that on Linux/g++ ?

**EDIT 1:**

so link the code dynamicaly, however as suspected the glibc is not the same on the SAS environment. I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: Extension Load Failure: OS Error: -1 (/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by 
 /folders/foobar/libfoo.so))
```

**EDIT 2:** 
I tried to tinker a little bit more with linkage options:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -fPIC -static /usr/lib64/libc.a -shared foo.cpp -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -o libfoo2.so
```

however this gives a similar error in SAS:

```
ERROR: Extension Load Failure: OS Error: -1 (/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by 
 /folders/myshortcuts/Desktop/libfoo2.so))
```

While tinkering I figured that `readelf` gives information about the libraries needed, however the libc.so remains always needed but not available on the SAS environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out that the environment from Centos 6.6 is close enough (maybe all that is needed is libc in version 2.12) to the SAS university distribution.

With the help of [wallstprog](http://btorpey.github.io/blog/2015/01/02/building-clang/) I figured out that I would need to install g++ 4.8.2 on Centos to be able to compile c++11 (as this is the version which is written in c++98 and therefore can be build from source on Centos).

Then it becomes trivial to compile:

```
g++ -fPIC -std=c++11 -c foo.cpp -o foo.o
g++ foo.o -shared -static-libstc++ -o libfoo.so
```

And this passed the link stage in the proc proto fine.